# Fazer atualizações na página automaticamente ao receber alguma informação - HTML, JS, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Eu e um amigo estamos desenvolvendo um jogo de navegador online, mas estamos com problema ao fazer atualizações em tempo real quando algum jogador faz uma ação. Tentei usar AJAX para atualizar a pagina a cada 1 segundo, mas me pareceu que usa muito processamento, queria saber se tem alguma forma de atualizar alguma informação apenas quando houver alguma atualização no jogo. Obs:(Seria um jogo de cartas).

```
        /* Requisição ajax, essa retorna a atualização */
    var intervalo = window.setInterval(tmp, 1000);
    function tmp() {
        var str = ("?php echo $party; ?>");
        var data_out = {str};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/php/att_sala.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: data_out,
            success: function (data){
                document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = data;
            },
            error: function (data){
            },
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: De uma lida nisso: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets), acho que vai lhe dar um norte.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito ser possível fazer de n formas,

Se é um jogo de cartas é baseado em turnos, defina um tempo máximo para cada turno e faça a requisição sempre que o tempo do turno acabar.

Se você não quiser esperar o tempo do turno todo crie um script php que informa de quem é a vez ou se já jogou, e fique fazendo requisições de 1 em 1 segundo (teste se o ajax não tá enviando mais de uma request), como esse script php não vai processar nada é gasto pouco processamento. Para implementar isso você só precisaria saber quem são os pares que tão jogando. Exemplo prático disso:

Tabela Partidas

```
id INT
id_jogadorA INT
id_jogadorB INT
jogadorAtual CHAR
```

vezDeQuem.php

```
<?php
   $jogadorA = $_GET['jogador1'];
   $jogadorB = $_GET['jogador2'];

  // Busca no banco a partida (não sei se você tá usando mysqli ou pdo (recomendo pdo)
  // Retorna o jogador atual
```

telaDaPartida.php

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'vezDeQuem.php?jogadorA=id&jogadorB=id',
   success: function(data) {
      if (data.jogadorAtual == A) {
         // minha vez
      } else {
         // continuo esperando
      }
   }
})
```

**importante:** para isto funcionar é importante ter um jogador desafiante (jogador A) e um jogador desafiado (jogador B), isso pode ser passado no url (?desafiante=id), isso pode ser colocado na tabela partidas, invés de jogadorA e jogadorB, desafiante e desafiado.

Você também pode fazer isso por turnos, use um contador que vai incrementando a cada turno, sempre que for turno par o jogador A joga, se for turno impar o jogador B joga.

Tabela partidas

```
id INT
id_jogadorA INT
id_jogadorB INT
turno INT
```

vezDeQuem.php

```
<?php
   $jogadorA = $_GET['jogador1'];
   $jogadorB = $_GET['jogador2'];

  // Busca no banco a partida (não sei se você tá usando mysqli ou pdo (recomendo pdo)
  // Retorna o turno
```

telaDaPartida.php

```
// Isso significa que vou jogar sempre em turnos ímpar (pq tô iniciando do 1)
const jogouPrimeiro = true;
$.ajax({
   url: 'vezDeQuem.php?jogadorA=id&jogadorB=id',
   success: function(data) {
      if (data.turno % 2 == 0) {
         // continuo esperando (considerando que iniciei o jogo em turnos ímpar)
      } else {
         // minha vez (considerando que iniciei o jogo em turnos ímpar)
      }
   }
})
```

**Observações:** Eu abstraí muita coisa até porque é algo trabalhoso de se fazer, mas espero que tenha entendido a mensagem. De todo jeito você vai precisar de uma tabela para as partidas e é importante saber que desafiou e quem tá sendo desafiado porque assim você consegue lógicas do tipo jogadorA e jogadorB, sabendo que o turno passou você pode atualizar a tela chamando seu script att_sala.php. Esperando o tempo completo do turno é muito mais simples, mas não é tão legal assim, você pode tentar turnos rápidos, mas tudo isso vai de como você quer que seja o jogo.